# Why is padding affecting the height of the container?

Tags: html, css

Ok,

Consider the following code:

```
<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-20 padright">       
        <h3 class="padhalf blue-header">
            This is 20% Wide
        </h3>        
    </div>    
    <div class="grid-80 padleft">
        <h3 class="padhalf blue-header">
            This is 80% Wide
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="clear: both; height: 15px;"></div><!-- Just a spacer -->

<div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-50 padright">       
        <h3 class="padhalf blue-header">
            This is 50% wide
        </h3>        
    </div>    
    <div class="grid-50 padleft">
        <h3 class="padhalf blue-header">
            This is 50% wide
        </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-20 { float: left; width: 20%; }
.grid-50 { float: left; width: 50%; }
.grid-80 { float: left; width: 80%; }

.grid-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
}
.grid-container:after {
    clear: both;
}

.blue-header {
    background-color: #00f;
    color: #fff;
}

.padhalf {
    padding: 0.5% 0.5% 0.7% 0.5%;
}

.padright {
    padding-right: 1%;
}

.padleft {
    padding-left: 1%;
}
```

And the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u4kzhswq/

I don't know why the height of the H3 elements changes when the width changes. Why does the width or padding affect the height?

When the parents are identical width, all is OK. When they are not, the height of the child H3 seems to change proportionately.

Thanks,

Comment: You mean the content wraps and the height increases??

Comment: What height are you referring to?  The text appears to be the same height, at least on Firefox, the height of the blue bars are all the same, except for the one that line wraps.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it's different is because you're using a padding in percentage.
The percentage is calculated on the width of the element.

As per the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp)

> % Specifies the padding in percent of the width of the containing
>   element

So if you're container is wider (in this case 80%), the padding % will be higher.

Comment: Thanks @vyx.ca - Didn't realize it was based on width and not height when it relates to height. Also here's the link to the Mozilla documentation, just so we don't promote w3 schools. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/padding

Answer (score -2):

Looked at your fiddle, you have the class `.padhalf` only on one element, this happens to be the element that is larger.

```
.padhalf {
  padding: 0.5% 0.5% 0.7% 0.5%;
}
```

When you call `padding` the numbers go top -> right -> bottom -> left

So with this you are saying you want padding `.5%` on all sides except on the bottom where you set `.7%`.

Removing that line with `.padhalf` will fix the height issue.
Here is the **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4kzhswq/1/)**

Comment: I believe this goes against the OP's intent

Comment: In retrospect, it wasn't exactly phrased the best, this is just how I interpreted it.